# Can I use http request routs of sails.js in web-socket

Tags: websocket, sails.js, httprequest

Sails.js support both web-socket and http-request api call.
I have some route for my rest api like

> get /api/v1/userController/fetch

but I can't call this route from socket, there is any way to bind this route in socket.io and call this route from both web-socket and http-request?

Comment: Sails has a built in client library `sails.io`. You can use that to make requests from client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an android library here:
http://joshuamarquez.me/2016/06/12/how-to-use-sails.io.js-in-java/

This library is an wrapper around socket.io and connect to sails project in both socket and http way.
don't know why they don't mention this library in sails documentation :|